# Node-REDでLost connection to serverのエラー

Tags: bluemix

Node-RED Starterのボイラープレートをdeployしてエディターを使用しています。これまでは普通に使えていたのですが、時折Lost connection to serverというエラーが発生するようになりました。とくに決まった操作で発生する訳でもないようで、時間がたつと問題なく動くようになったりもします。なにか回避方法はありませんか?

Answer (score 1):

Lost connectionの発生理由は一つではないので絶対的な解法ではありませんが、Node-REDにhttpsでアクセスすることで回避できる場合があります。
WebブラウザでURLとしてhttpsを指定してNode-REDのエディターにアクセスしてみてください。